# How to preinstall Gapps on android x86 AOSP?

Tags: android-x86

I have managed to download and build the androidX86 src. When I ran the .iso image on a VM, I noticed that the AOSP does not include the GApps. I guess this is expected in some respect. Does anyone know how to put the Gapps in the androidX86 src so when I build an .iso image I can have the google apps preinstalled or alternatively just install the GApps . Thank you.

Comment: There is a stackexchange community especifically for android, maybe there someone can help you: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this modop : https://github.com/opengapps/aosp_build

I just notice you, the path of the manifest is in .repo/manifests/android-x86-X.X-rx.xml or the default.xml file if you dont used special manifest to DL (like -m android-x86-8.1-r1.xml at the end of the repo init commmand)

And you don't have to put these 2 lines :

```
<project path="vendor/opengapps/sources/arm" name="arm" clone-depth="1" revision="master" remote="nezor" />
<project path="vendor/opengapps/sources/arm64" name="arm64" clone-depth="1" revision="master" remote="nezor" />
```

You depend of x86 not arm and it can make you issue if you put them.

after add it, do your `repo sync` commands.

and the makefile to change is in `device/generic/x86_64/android_x86_64.mk`, add package of opengapps you want. (comparaison here : https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Package-Comparison)

I Hope this is usefull.

Regards, Bastien